# oracle sql views specifying further criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

If you have created a view in oracle sql like

```
 create view view_item as
 select *
 from employees
```

Then you can call it like `select * from view_item`. However, I was wondering whether it's possible to further specify some creteria which is not part of the initial view specification such as

```
  select * from view_item where name='Mark'
```

This one won't work unless I have specified it into the view beforehand.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? As long as there is a clomun named 'name' in employees...

Comment: I have tried but it's telling me ora-00904 employees.name: invalid identifier and then 00904.00000 - "%s":invalid identifier

Comment: Firstly try to avoid "select *", as your result will change when the underlying tables change. Show the definition of the employees table or view.

Comment: Do you use the same user when you select from the view?

Comment: Oh, I have actually found out that you don't need to specify the table name like employees.name but just name since it's creating some virtual table, isn't? Also, if the underlying tables stay the same why should I not use select *?

Comment: When you run `create view view_item as select * from employees`, Oracle actually creates a view with the specific columns that the table currently has - to see this run `select text from user_views where view_name='VIEW_ITEM'`.  This doesn't matter really, but you might be surprised to find that if you now add a new column to the table it does not automatically get added to the view.

Comment: Oh thanks for that but I would not add other columns. It will simply be the same query being used by other people every day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is a query that is being saved on the DBMS so where you run:

```
 create view view_item as
 select *
 from employees
```

you just save the query somewhere in the DBMS memory.

when you run :

```
select * from view_item
```

you actually run:

```
 select *
 from employees
```

BUT - here's the fun part - for you it looks like a table, so you can append it with a where :

```
select * from view_item where name ='Mark'
```

will map to

```
 select *
 from employees where name = 'Mark'
```

Let's take it furthere, let's say you created a view with a where clause

```
 create view view_item as
 select *
 from employees
 where salary < 10000
```

than the same query from before:

```
select * from view_item where name ='Mark'
```

will map to

```
select *
from employees 
where salary < 10000 and name = 'Mark'
```

a DBMS is pretty cool :)

you should play with it to understand exactly what's going in the background, because you can use it for permissions and other things..

Comment: Yeah. I did not realize that it looks like a table from where you can further specify criteria. But why should I not use select * as StephaneM suggested?

Comment: It depends of the need... If for example you use a view for shortening what you write - you should put the most restrictive condition, though the answer would change if you use it for permision (and than you'll have to query from a different user, which will have "select" permission only on the view, and not on the base table)

Comment: If you'll describe what your goal is, and why you want to use a view, I'll be able to be more helpful :)

Comment: I would like to use a view to pull out some data from sql and using it for a macro in Excel but I would like to allow the user to be able to select some criteria when querying from the sql server so I guess using select * with further specifying some where clauses like the example above should not be an issue?

Comment: Then for it you can use whatever you wanted to - create a view, and just pad it with a where when you need to. Since you don't want to limit the "excel" user permissions, and you grant them also access to the regular data (I assume you are the excel user too) - you shouldn't bother yourself with more than just creating the view. You can totaly think of the view as a table in this case, which has a virtual data that you target the excel